# Dependency Injection into NetworkBoundResource with Dagger

Tags: android, dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

I am using the AWS SDK and trying to adopt the NetworkBoundResource pattern. The problem that I'm facing is that after an hour, the AWS session expires and you need to refresh the credentials. I have not found a good way of doing this except catching a NotAuthorizedException, refreshing the credentials through the authenticationHandler, and refreshing using the CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider. To do this, you need an instance of the CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider and CognitoUserPool in the NetworkBoundResource class. I'm wondering how or if it possible to simply @Injet these into this class. (Like how you would inject a Dao or Service into the ViewModel constructor). Here's what I have so far:

**ApiModule**

```
@Provides
@Singleton
CognitoUserPool provideUserPool(Application application) {
    return new CognitoUserPool(
            application,
            application.getString(R.string.user_pool_id),
            application.getString(R.string.app_client_id),
            application.getString(R.string.app_client_secret),
            Endpoints.REGION
    );
}

/*
 * The method returns the CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider object
 */

@Provides
@Singleton
CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider provideCredentialsProvider(Application application) {
    return new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
            application,
            application.getString(R.string.identity_pool_id),
            Endpoints.REGION
    );
}
```

**NetworkBoundResource**

```
public abstract class NetworkBoundResource {

private CognitoUserPool cognitoUserPool;

private CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider cognitoCachingCredentialsProvider;

private final MediatorLiveData<Resource<JSONObject>> result = new MediatorLiveData<>();

public NetworkBoundResource() {

}

@MainThread
@Inject
public NetworkBoundResource(CognitoUserPool cognitoUserPool, CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider cognitoCachingCredentialsProvider) {
    if(null == cognitoUserPool) Timber.e("CognitoUserPool is null");
    if(null == cognitoCachingCredentialsProvider) Timber.e("CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider is null");

    this.cognitoUserPool = cognitoUserPool;
    this.cognitoCachingCredentialsProvider = cognitoCachingCredentialsProvider;

    setValue(Resource.loading(null));
    AppExecutors.getInstance().networkIO().execute(this::fetchFromNetwork);
}
```

This throws an error:

> "error: @Inject is nonsense on the constructor of an abstract class"

However the following just produces null values for both.

```
@Inject
CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider cognitoCachingCredentialsProvider;

@Inject
CognitoUserPool cognitoUserPool;
```

Currently all NetworkBoundResource is called from within a Repository (which the ViewModel creates). Here's an example:

**MainRepository**

```
    public LiveData<Resource<JSONObject>> getUser() {
    return new NetworkBoundResource() {

        @Override
        protected LambdaResponseWrapper createCall() {
            Timber.i("getUser()");
            return mainApiService.getUser(new HashMap<>());
        }

        @Override
        protected void processResponse(JSONObject response) throws JSONException {
            Timber.i("processResponse - user");
            UserEntity user = new UserEntity(response);
            userDao.insertUser(user);
        }
    }.asLiveData();
}
```

I am able to do the above in a Fragment/Activity but I'm assuming it has something to do with

```
AndroidInjection.inject(this);
```

And

**ActivityModule**

```
@Module
public abstract class ActivityModule {

@ContributesAndroidInjector()
abstract MainActivity contributeMainActivity();
```

As you can probably tell, I have no idea what I'm doing and find Dagger/DI quite confusing. Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks

Comment: How do you normally get an instance of `NetworkBoundResource`?

Comment: @Nitrodon I added an example of my MainRepository. Each call returns a new instance of NetworkBoundResource as live data

Comment: https://square.github.io/okhttp/4.x/okhttp/okhttp3/-authenticator/